# passing arguments, ruby script

Tags: ruby, parameter-passing

i'm trying to pass 2 empty arrays to a method but I get an argument exception... i read around but still can't figure out why is this happening...

code:

```
file = File.read("place_code.google.com")
paths = []
urls = []

def parseLog(file, paths)
    file.each_line do |line|
        match = line.match(/([a-z0-9]*GET\s)(.*puzzle\S*)/)
        if match 
            paths << match[2] 
        end
    end
    return paths
end
```

error:

```
:in `parseLog': wrong number of arguments (0 for 2) (ArgumentError)
```

Comment: Mind showing us how you invoke this method?

Comment: Hmmmmm... YOU sire are right, thanks for pointing it out... i forgot to change the invoke's arguments after some changes. thank you. Make it an answere, so i can accept the good hint as an answere. I forggot to paramterizes the call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are invoking your method, you aren't passing in the required parameters. To invoke your method you'd do something like:

```
file = File.read("place_code.google.com")
paths = []
urls = []
class NewClass
     def initalize
     end
     def parseLog(file, paths)
        file.each_line do |line|
          match = line.match(/([a-z0-9]*GET\s)(.*puzzle\S*)/)
          if match 
            paths << match[2] 
          end
       end
      return paths
     end
  end
yourClass = NewClass.new()
yourClass.parseLog(file, path)
```